# How do Boba Fett and other Star Wars characters fire weapons without using their hands?

Tags: star-wars, technology, the-clone-wars

In the Star Wars Universe, how does a bounty hunter (such as Boba Fett) use their gauntlet weapons without touching the buttons to launch it? For instance, they shoot wires/darts etc., but their hands are not seen near the button.

Comment: We have technology that can do that in real life. Convert brain waves to commands and such. This isn't particularly far-fetched sci fi.

Answer (score 32):

In the cases of Jango & Boba Fett, the helmet is the key. Mandalorian armor includes a sub-vocal mic in the helmet that can activate features of the armor by using voice commands. Similar to the throat-mic system used by modern special forces, this allows the wearer to issue vocal commands to the armor without emitting audible sound. Some other features of the armor do indeed require manual activation, as when he prepared to shoot Luke in "Return of the Jedi" (right before Solo knocks him into the Sarlacc). Note that his right hand is on the button to fire the dart:

[image]

Comment: That .gif is hypnotic.