# How are the jetpacks controlled in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, technology, boba-fett

So we see lots of people with jetpacks in Star Wars (okay maybe not mostly just Jango and Boba Fett but still) but they never explained how they are used. We never see them press a button to use their jetpack. So how are they used?

Comment: [Poorly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v4xKHWQckfI)

Comment: Is a Legends answer acceptable?

Comment: Well, there's Death Watch from Clone Wars, so I say that counts as "lots of people". :)

Comment: @Jonah Sure as long as it is not something Disney is likely to have changed (such as the fate of Luke or whatever).

Comment: Related: [How do Boba Fett and other Star Wars characters fire weapons without using their hands?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/77004/how-do-boba-fett-and-other-star-wars-characters-fire-weapons-without-using-their?rq=1)

Comment: Go, go gadget, jetpack!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Wrist and hand controls

According to *Galladinium's Fantastic Technology*, a *Star Wars* roleplaying game supplement (and thus Legends):

> Wrist or hand controls adjust the angle and pitch of both input and
> exhaust vanes, allowing for both vertical and horizontal flight.
>
> —*Galladinium's Fantastic Technology*

[image]

### Voice commands

This applies more specifically to Jango Fett's jetpack, but presumably other jet packs had similar features.

> The main control console was located on one of Jango's forearm panels.
> However, it often happened that Jango had his hands full (of weapons)
> when he needed to ignite the jets, and so a verbal control interface
> was included in the bounty hunter's helmet. With just a word, Jango
> could be up and away.
>
> —*The Official Star Wars Fact File #60*

Comment: This needs moar upvotes because freehand red circles.